# Multiple choice game in Python using Tkinter, Counting correct answers

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a group project where we must create a simple program and we have chosen to make a multiple choice game using Tkinter. We have constructed most of the game already, but are having a problem when keeping a count of the correct answers. We are using Radiobuttons to list the answers for each question, however if the user clicks the button more than once it keeps incrementing the count as many times as they click it. Here is the code that we have. Please excuse the messiness, as we have not quite gone through to clean it up, as well as it is a bit of a beginner project and we are not the most experienced group of programmers.

(I am purposefully not including the complete code because the file paths for the images we have are directly linked to the home computer so they would not be able to be used anyways)

```
root = Tk()
counter = 0
d = ''
var = StringVar()
def next():
    global i,img,groups,listanswer, questions, randint, key,d, counter
    s = randint(1,4)
    key = random.choice(list(questions.keys()))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(key))       
    panel = Label(root, image = img)
    panel.grid(column=0, row=0)

    b = []
    c = listanswer.index(str(questions.get(key)))
    d = listanswer[c]
    b.append(d)
    listanswer.remove(d)

    def selection():
        global counter, d, sel
        sel = str(var.get())
        if sel == d:
            counter +=1 
    i=1

    while i<5:
        a=random.choice(listanswer)
        b.append(a)
        if s!=i:
            Radiobutton(root, text=a, padx=20,variable=var,  
             value=a,command=selection).grid(column=0, row=i)
        listanswer.remove(a)
        i+=1

    R1 = Radiobutton(root, text=d, padx=20,variable=var, value=d,command = 
          selection).grid(column=0, row=s)
    listanswer=listanswer+b
    questions.pop(key)


    counterlabel.configure(text='%g' %counter)

counterlabel=Label(root,width=8)
counterlabel.grid(column=1, row=5)
counterval=Label(root, width=10, text='Correct:')
counterval.grid(column=0,row=5)

next=Button(root,text='next',command=next)
next.grid(column=2, row=2)

var = IntVar()

label = Label(root)
label.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code above raise errors. If you want help, please, put self-contained code. You are missing several imports, but more important, some global variables like `questions` are not defined, and this makes imposible to run the script. You should try to isolate the problem in a smaller, self-contained script before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the correctly every time you click on the radiobutton the code will check if *that* answer is correct. If it is, you increase the counter.
Instead, I recommend checking *all* answers when any of the radiobuttons is clicked, and set the counter accordingly (i.e. the counter resets every time you click).

Hopefully this helps!